# removing list with a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I understand how to remove elements when there are list and a variable, but is there a way to remove elements from a list using another list? EXAMPLE: (list 1 2 3 4 5)(list 1 2 3) yields (list 4 5)

Comment: Is the same result expected for (list 4 1 2 3 5) and (list 4 5 1 2 3)?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to do this?  If you're trying to represent things like set subtraction, the list representation may not be appropriate.  Racket includes sets as a data structure:  http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as with a variable, but you need to use the member function instead of equal?:

```
#lang racket
; remove every element included in rlist from flist
(define (remove-list rlist flist)
  (if (empty? flist)
      '()
      (let ((c (car flist)))
        (if (member c rlist) ; <====
            (remove-list rlist (cdr flist))
            (cons c (remove-list rlist (cdr flist)))))))

(remove-list (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(4 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Racket this is pretty simple, just use the [`remove*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._remove%2a%29%29) built-in procedure:

```
(remove* (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(4 5)
```